# Why does the default value not render on Mat Select dropdown?

Tags: angular, select, drop-down-menu, default-value

I'm fairly new to Angular, but unless I remove the ngModel from my Mat Select (which is used for my GraphQL mutation), it won't render the default value. My goal is to have the dropdown pre-filled with the user's current position.

```
<mat-list-item>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Location</mat-label>
        <mat-select [value]="user.position" matNativeControl required [(ngModel)]="newLocation">
          <mat-option value="Top">Top</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Front">Front</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Middle">Middle</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Back">Back</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Right">Right</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Left">Left</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
</mat-list-item>
```

Here is the TS file:

```
  updateUser(userId) {
    this.apollo
      .mutate({
        mutation: EDIT_USER,
        variables: {
          input: {
            userPosition: this.newLocation,
          }
        }
      })
      .subscribe(
        ({ data }) => {
          if (data['editUser'].complete) {
            this.getAssets();
            const user = this.assetDetails.users.find((s) => s.id === userId);
            user.userPosition = this.newLocation;
          }
        },
        (error) => {}
      );
  }
```

I have verified that user.position gives me the correct value, because it renders once [(ngModel)]="newLocation" is removed, but like I said earlier, is needed for my mutation. I can't seem to figure out a workaround. Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out with the help of the other answers:

I basically had to set the value in ngModel (newLocation) to a variable that held the initial value, before the mutation) rather than setting the new value to 'newLocation'. That way, it will render the initial / default value. I then passed that variable as a parameter to my mutation.

Here is a snippet of the updated code:

```
<mat-list-item>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Location</mat-label>
        <mat-select [value]="user.position" matNativeControl required [(ngModel)]="user.userPosition">
          <mat-option value="Top">Top</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Front">Front</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Middle">Middle</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Back">Back</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Right">Right</mat-option>
          <mat-option value="Left">Left</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
</mat-list-item>
```

I then called my function like so:

```
updateUser(user.id, user.userPosition)
```

And the TS:

```
  updateUser(userId, position) {
    this.apollo
      .mutate({
        mutation: EDIT_USER,
        variables: {
          input: {
            userPosition: position,
          }
        }
      })
      .subscribe(
        ({ data }) => {
          if (data['editUser'].complete) {
            this.getAssets();
            const user = this.assetDetails.users.find((s) => s.id === userId);
            user.userPosition = position;
          }
        },
        (error) => {}
      );
  }
```

A really simple fix. ngModel and value can't be used simultaneously, as ngModel takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `matNativeControl` and the `[(ngModel)]` binding. After this, the predefined value will work (If the `user.position` value is equal any options value. This is case sensitive).

Comment: Right, but I'm in need of the ngModel so that my GraphQL mutation can work properly. Not worried about case sensitivity

Comment: The `[(ngModel)]` rewrite your `value` attribute, so you need to pass in your `[(ngModel)]` variable the excepted predefined value.

Comment: Please post your TS file, with the `newLocation` variable.

Comment: I added a snippet of the TS file with the newLocation variable

Answer (score 1):

You should either use ngModel or Value, not both together.